# Как ограничить, отправку сообщения, в группе телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram

Подскажите, как ограничить отправку сообщения в группу, для пользователей в телеграмме, чтобы было разрешено, только из белого списка id пользовальтелей и как это все прописать.
Например из misql базы, чтобы считывало id пользователей, кому можно писать в группе, но тогда нужно будет, чтобы по команде из бота, вносить эти id, или же из файла, чтобы считывал, все разрешенные id.

Объясните мне, почему, два разный id, 1 я нажал старт в боте и записался, мой настоящий id, 2 я написал в группе текст, но Id уже другой? последние цифры, 2 id стёр.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает, но почему id не записывает в базу, хотя файл создал.

```html
import requests
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import connect
import cursor as cursor
import aiogram
import logging
import math
import os
#import time
import asyncio
import random
from time import time
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ChatMember
from aiogram.types import InlineQuery, \
    InputTextMessageContent, InlineQueryResultArticle
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from asyncio import sleep
from contextlib import suppress
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import (MessageToEditNotFound, MessageCantBeEdited, MessageCantBeDeleted, MessageToDeleteNotFound)
#from data import config
from aiogram.types import ChatInviteLink
from aiogram.types import ChatJoinRequest
from aiogram.types import ChatActions
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
import sqlite3

logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s [ LINE:%(lineno)+3s ]#%(levelname)+8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)



conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_id INTEGER, username TEXT)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

class SQLither:

    def __init__(self, database) -> object:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def exists_user(self, user_id):
        """Проверка существования пользователя в БД"""
        return bool(self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)).fetchone())

    def add_to_db(self, user_id, username):
        """Добавление пользователя в БД"""
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,)) and self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('username') VALUES(?)", (username,))
        self.conn.commit()

db = SQLither("users.db")

API_TOKEN = 'moi_token'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())
```

Пожалуйста, желательно для библиотеки Aiogram.

Даже если Вы мне поможете, чтобы он писал все id, как закрыть стену, чтобы открыта была, если id в белом списке и прописать к хендлеру текст

```html
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def handler_text(message):
```

или к этому хендлеру, текст фото видео и тд.

```html
@dp.message_handler()
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону sqlite + aiogram

Comment: Подскажите, как это всё прописать.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html

Comment: Как говорится, ли ж бы что отправить, но это мне не поможет, объясните за чем мне это Этот обработчик будет вызываться, когда пользователь отправляет команду `/start` или `/help` ?  если пользователю не надо вызывать эти команды? мне нужна отдельная команда, только для меня, чтобы вносить id в базу и я вообще не понимаю в misql я там ничего не слеплю, Я прошу помощи, чтобы подсказали рабочий код. мне нужно к этому хендлеру, все прописать @dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

Comment: Как говориться лиж бы за меня все сделали. Я вам скинул две крупные документации по которым сам написал не одного бота. Ваша проблема не ясна, конкретных попыток что либо сделать я не наблюдаю. Чем вам помочь? Написать за вас код? Это не тот форум

Comment: у меня есть код, но как дальше все прописать.
Вот пример.
` 
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def handler_text(message):
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usermember ( 
    user_id INTEGER,
    username TEXT
    )""")

    connect.commit()

    #Add values in fields
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.chat.username
    print(type(user_id))
    #print(type(chat_id))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usermember(user_id,username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,username))
    connect.commit() 
`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136883/discussion-between-tikeo-and-tomato-magnet-regulato).

Comment: я вам советую создать новый вопрос по поводу id.

Comment: Уже создан, но ни кто, не пишет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor

conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
c = conn.cursor()
#Создание таблицы если не сущ.
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_id INTEGER)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

class SQLither:

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def exists_user(self, user_id):
        """Проверка существования пользователя в БД"""
        return bool(self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)).fetchone())

    def add_to_db(self, user_id):
        """Добавление пользователя в БД"""
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,))
        self.conn.commit()


bot = Bot(token="") 
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

db = SQLither("db.db")

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def message_handler(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    if not db.exists_user(user_id):
        #Если пользователя нет в БД - добавить.
        db.add_to_db(user_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо, но почему не мой id записало, а id группы -цифры, id  пользователя без минуса пишет, так же имя пользователя не записало.

Comment: Сделал так user_id = message.from_user.id
Но почему записывает, не мой id а другой какой та.
Мой такой 19561цифры а записало 10879цифры

Comment: message.from_user.id <- должен быть ваш ID

Comment: Я это понимаю, но почему же, он отличается, от того, что мне  мой другой бот пишет и все боты пишут, которые показывают id пользователя, от того, что пишет в таблице?

Comment: А может быть такое, если я к боту обращаюсь и жму старт, показывает один id, а когда в группе пишу, то другой id? так это что получается, у пользователя по 2 id или как?

Comment: Возможно вы в группе пишите от имени сообщества(группы, чата), я с этим не сталкивался, но в теории мб мб. В итоге выдает id группы.

Comment: Я пишу, не от имени группы, а от имени обычного пользователя.